# Firestore: getDoc Only Returning One Field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using Firestore with React.

On authentication I have the following code which will either update the lastLogin only, or create the user and add in a createdDate:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {       
    const userRef = doc(db, 'users', user.uid);
    getDoc(userRef).then(docSnapshot) => {
        var userData = { lastLogin: todayMMDDYYY };

        if (!docSnapshot.exists()) {                                  
             userdata.dateJoined = todayMMDDYYY; 
        }                             
        
        setDoc(userRef, userData, { merge: true });
    }
});
```

Later, I query the user object to get a list of games with this code:

```
    export const _getUserGames = async () => {
        var uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
        const userRef = doc(db, "users", uid);
        var userRecord = await getDocFromServer(userRef).then((snapshot) => {
            return snapshot.data();
        });
    
        var allGames = { ...userRecord.gamesPlayed ?? {}, ...userRecord.adHocGamesPlayed ?? {} };
    
        if (!allGames) {
            allGames = {};
        }
    
        return allGames;
    }
```

My problem is that this last code is only returning the lastLogin in the user object, like this

`{ lastLogin: "08/22/2023" }`

I can set a breakpoint and see that this is the entire object returned. However, this is only happening in one environment. I have two firebase projects with their own FIrestore database, for simplicity Prod and Dev.

When I run locally (pointing to either Firestore database), I get the full user object. When I run the code in Dev, I get the full user object. When I run this in Prod only the lastLogin is returned in the user object. When the code that sets the lastLogin is commented out then Prod will return the full user object.

Not sure what could have the code returning only the lastLogin field.

EDIT to add expected data:
Existing users should return a document that looks like this

```
{ 
    dateJoined: "08/01/2023",
    lastLogin: "08/23/2023",
    gamesPlayed: { wingspan: 5, pandemic: 3 },
    players: { Sue: {...}, Joe: {...},
    adHocGamesPlayed: { Everdell: 10 }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this code to do differently?  Show us the data you're working with.  All you've shown us right now is that you write a single field `lastLogin` into the document and nothing else, so that's all I would expect to see coming out of it.  Please edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: Also, no need to mix `await` and `then` in the same code - just use `await`. `then` is adding nothing except more lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the ```await``` and ```then``` tip. I will update it. I added the data I expect. This code works in most of my environments where it returns all of the user data. For some reason my "prod" environment is the only one behaving like this.

Answer (score 0):

While I am still not 100% sure on the details of what caused this I was able to get it to work. Thanks in part to **Doug Stevenson** for his advice on not using both `await` and `then` which prompted me to go back and clean up the code.

First, I removed the code setting the login date from the `onAuthStateChanged` and put it inside the actual login from the login button. It looks like this now:

```
 const googleHandler = async () => {
        provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });

        signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
            .then(async (result) => {
                const userRef = doc(db, 'users', result.user.uid);
                var userSnapshot = await getDoc(userRef);
                var docSnapshot = userSnapshot.data();

                var userData = { lastLogin: todayMMDDYYYY };
                if (!docSnapshot) {
                    userData.dateJoined = todayMMDDYYYY;
                    userData.gamesPlayed = {};
                    userData.players = {};
                    userData.adHocGamesPlayed = {};
                }

                await setDoc(userRef, userData, { merge: true });
            });
    };
```

After that, I updated the code that gets the user object (the one that wasn't returning the full object before). I prefer `await` to `then()` so I went that route. With brand new users I did notice this code being called before the user object was fully written to Firestore, so I added a check to do return an empty object if the userDoc._document is undefined.

```
export const _getUserGames = async () => {
    var uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
    const userRef = doc(db, "users", uid);
    var userDoc = await getDoc(userRef);
    if (!userDoc?._document) {
        return {};
    }

    var userRecord = userDoc.data();
    var allGames = { ...userRecord.gamesPlayed ?? {}, ...userRecord.adHocGamesPlayed ?? {} };
    if (!allGames) {
        allGames = {};
    }
    return allGames;
}
```

At this point the code is working. I am not sure if I just had a weird race condition, or something else was going on with Firestore, but the entire user object is now being returned.

Before, I would just get
 `{ lastLogin: "08/23/2023" }`

Now I get the full object:

```
{
    dateJoined: "08/01/2023",
    lastLogin: "08/23/2023",
    gamesPlayed: { wingspan: 5, pandemic: 3 },
    players: { Sue: {...}, Joe: {...},
    adHocGamesPlayed: { Everdell: 10 }
}
```